# Relative layout inside 2 dimensional scrollview it's resizing itself when a view is added to the limits of the layout

Tags: android, layout, view, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm developing a app that works like an editor and where you can drag and drop elements to a layout, but i need to have my layout with dimensions that sometimes are bigger than the screen size so i need to allow scroll in both ways on the layout.

I'm doing it like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layoutScroll"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/trashBtn"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LabelTypeTextView"
    >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layoutScrollHor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/labelCanvas"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:background="@drawable/label_canvas"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/trashBtn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LabelTypeTextView">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

The issue is that when i add a element to the end of my relative layout, the layout increases it's dimensions and i wanted it to just clip the element.

Visual Example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quh8Y.png)

Here the pink row was the end of the layout but when i dragged the element to a position where it wouldn't be able to fully stay inside the layout it resizes the layout adding the blue space.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try android:fillViewport="true" in ScrollView